# Why am getting segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I have some troubles here... 
When am trying to debug my Project ... I find an error at line 73. However, If I only run my project, I don't  have any error of segmentation fault:

Here is my code

http://pastebin.com/Div4yYWY

My data's proof

http://pastebin.com/Div4yYWY

I hope someone help me

Comment: Why don't you drop using `char*` and just use `std::string`?

Comment: show effort please. we are not here to debug your assignment for you

Comment: This is a throw-away question. You throw at us all that tons of code and ask us to debug it for you. As an additional bonus, we also get all variable and function names in Spanish, just in case we were planning to learn a new language. Now, here's the deal: You debug the code, extract the relevant snippet where you think the problem is. Then, add it here as part of your question and explain exactly what you've tried and what you're struggling to understand. In return, one (or possibly more) of us, will pinpoint the problem and tell you what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I just glanced at your code, but...

```
line 55: void **auxVoid, **exacto =  NULL;
...
line 71: for (int i=0; i<pos; i++) auxVoid[i] = exacto[i]; <-- 
line 72: if (exacto!= NULL) delete[] exacto;
```

you call `exacto[i]` while exacto is still null.